# Close a pull request without merging it into the upstream branch in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to close a pull request **without** merging it into the upstream branch?

I am using gitflow and so I want the *developer* who started the feature branch to **finish** the feature branch rather than *reviewer* to merge the feature branch.

Looks like this facility is available in [github](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/closing-a-pull-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So if you want to merge but not delete the feature branch, there is an option. Just uncheck the delete check box.

Now using gitflow, you can now finish the branch. Then git flow will delete the branch locally as well as remotely. And before deleting locally, it will merge changes from the feature branch to the develop locally.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can abandon the Pull Request, it will close it without merging:

[image]

Comment: But is abandoning same as close?

Comment: I think so. Hot go you demonstrate “close”?

Comment: Can one then delete the underlying branch?